# Creating and Interpreting Regression Equation

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, interpretation

A question is asking to create a relevant regression equation and test a hypothesis. It is asking to test whether the effect of studying on SAT scores is different when consuming daily 2 cups of coffee as opposed to when consuming 50 cups of coffee.

The regression that I came up with is:

$Score =$$\beta_0 + \beta_1 CUPS + \beta_2 STUDYING + \beta_3 CUPS*STUYDING +\epsilon$

where Score = SAT score, CUPS = daily consumed cups of coffee, STUDYING = hours spent studying.

Is $\beta_3$ the additional effect of studying on SAT score when consuming coffee? If so, would the null and alternative hypothesis be:

$H_0: 2\beta_3 = 100\beta_3$

$H_A: 2\beta_3 \neq 100\beta_3$

Comment: The hypothesis looks wrong. How can 2 == 100 with the same coefficient?

Comment: I think you can test for the coefficients for (2_CUPS * Studying) against the coefficient for (50_CUPS * Studying). Remember, your software should split out interaction terms for the two variables you have. Assume Studying is a continuous variable.